# How to show that f in $C[0,2\pi]$ is continuous under "shifting" to $[\delta, 2\pi-\delta]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f\in C[0,2\pi]$ and $f_\delta := f$ in $[\delta , 2\pi - \delta],f_{\delta}(0)=f_{\delta}(2\pi)=\frac{1}{2}(f(0)+f(2\pi))$ and $f_\delta$ is linear in $[0,\delta]$ and also in $[2\pi - \delta , 2\pi]$

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0 $ such that : $||f-f_\delta||<\epsilon$.

How to prove this?

Comment: Which norm are talking about?

Comment: the norm induced by : $||f||:= (f,f)^{1/2} = (\int_{0}^{2\pi}f^2)^{1/2})$

Comment: I think this question raised when you were thinking about Fourier series, but as the question stated it is not related to Fourier series at all

Comment: I tried to correct the title, is it better suited now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f=f_\delta$ on $[\delta,2\pi-\delta]$, then
$$
\Vert f-f_\delta\Vert=
\left(\int\limits_{[0,\delta]}|f(x)-f_\delta(x)|^2 dx+\int\limits_{[2\pi-\delta,2\pi]}|f(x)-f_\delta(x)|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}
$$
Let $M=\max\limits_{x\in[0,2\pi]}|f(x)|$, then for all $x\in[0,2\pi]$ we have $|f_\delta(x)|\leq M$ and we conculde
$$
\Vert f-f_\delta\Vert\leq\left(\int\limits_{[0,\delta]}(2M)^2 dx+\int\limits_{[2\pi-\delta,2\pi]}(2M)^2 dx\right)^{1/2}=2M(2\delta)^{1/2}
$$
So for a given $\varepsilon$ it is enough to set $\delta=\varepsilon^2/(8M^2)$.